# Using Where to specify different generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm writing a [bijective dictionary class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321), but I want to ensure the two generic types are not the same type for two reasons.

Firstly, I would like it to implement the `IDictionary` interface in both directions, but

```
public class BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDictionary<TValue, TKey>
```

gives me " 'BijectiveDictionary<TKey,TValue>' cannot implement both 'IDictionary<TKey,TValue>' and 'IDictionary<TValue,TKey>' because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions " (which is understandable, but undesirable.)

Secondly, I would like to write an optimized solution if both types are the same.

```
public class BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : TKey
{
    // Optimized solution
}

public class BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDictionary<TValue, TKey> where TValue : !TKey
{
    // Standard solution
}
```

Is this possible?

If not, I can consider not implementing `IDictionary`, but I couldn't guarantee `TValue this[TKey key]` and `TKey this[TValue key]` would be different, which would be unfortunate.

---

It looks like the problem here is that when the two types are the same, the special cases arise.

My original intent was to create a dictionary which maps exactly one key to exactly one value, and visa versa, such that for every `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(X, Y)`, a `KeyValuePair<TValue, TKey>(Y, X)` exists as well.

When `TKey` = `TValue`, then this can be simplified down to a single dictionary:

```
public T this[T key]
{
    get { return this[key]; }
    set
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        base.Add(value, key);
    }
}
```

In this case, you cannot `Add(2,3); Add(3,4)` because `Add(2,3)` maps `3` to `2` as well, and `[3]` would return `2`.

However, [Jaroslav Jandek's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172680/using-where-to-specify-difference-generics/3172919#3172919) proposed using a second dictionary to do this for cases when `TKey` != `TValue`. And although this works wonderfully for those cases, (and what I decided to implement, in the end) it doesn't quite follow my original intent when `TKey` = `TValue`, by allowing `Add(2,3); Add(3,4)` to map a single key `3` to two values (`2` in one direction, and `4` in the other,) though I believe strictly speaking is still a valid bijective function.

Comment: What are you using the dictionary for? Do you even need the surjection part of your dictionary?
That said, the code in my answer handles all your cases (implementing IDictonary, providing bijection and handling cases where TKey == TValue).

Comment: If you want bijection to itself for `TKey == TValue`, you could use `SelfBijectiveDictionary<T> : BijectiveDictionary<T, T> {...}` and overriding it's `Add` method and checking first `if (base.Contains(key) || this.Reversed.Contains(value)) throw ...`.
The classes should be named differently anyway, because one is bijective `X->Y` and the other `S->S` (bijective to itself).

Comment: Pointing out the difference between `X->Y` and `S->S` helps a lot. Sorry for all the confusion! And yes - I'm making two separately named Dictionaries for them. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this (different approach):

```
public class BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public BijectiveDictionary<TValue, TKey> Reversed { get; protected set; }

    public BijectiveDictionary()
    {
        this.Reversed = new BijectiveDictionary<TValue,TKey>(true);
        this.Reversed.Reversed = this;
    }

    protected BijectiveDictionary(bool reversedWillBeSetFromTheCallingBiji) { }

    protected void AddRaw(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
    }

    // Just for demonstration - you should implement the IDictionary interface instead.
    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        this.Reversed.AddRaw(value, key);
    }

    public static explicit operator BijectiveDictionary<TValue, TKey>(BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue> biji)
    {
        return biji.Reversed;
    }
}
```

and in code:

```
BijectiveDictionary<int, bool> a = new BijectiveDictionary<int, bool>();

a.Add(5, true);
a.Add(6, false);

Console.WriteLine(a[5]);// => True
Console.WriteLine(((BijectiveDictionary < bool, int>)a)[true]);// => 5
//or
Console.WriteLine(a.Reversed[true]);// => 5
```

Comment: Note: the explicit cast `Console.WriteLine(((BijectiveDictionary < int, int>)a)[true]);` **won't work** when the types of sets are the same. It is for obvious reasons - I wanted to point it out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Re optimising it, one option there might be a strategy based on a static initializer, that chooses an appropriate concrete implementation for the same-type case, but otherwise; i.e.

```
public class BijectiveDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    static readonly ISomeStrategy strategy;
    static BijectiveDictionary() {
        if(typeof(TKey) == typeof(TValue)) {
            strategy = ...
        } else {
            strategy = ...
        }
    }
}
```

but you will almost certainly find yourself using `MakeGenericType` and reflection to create the instance (but once created it should be fine - and you only do that once).

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, this can be done!  I use a differentiating method, instead of qualifier(s) limiting the types.

It does not unify, in fact it might be better than if it did because you can tease the separate interfaces apart.

See my post here, with a fully working example in another context.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12361409/471129

Basically, what you do is add another type parameter to `IIndexer`, so that it become `IIndexer <TKey, TValue, TDifferentiator>`.

Then you when you use it twice, you pass "First" to the 1st use, and "Second" for the 2nd use

So, class Test becomes:  `class Test<TKey, TValue> : IIndexer<TKey, TValue, First>, IIndexer<TValue, TKey, Second>`

Thus, you can do `new Test<int,int>()`

where First, and Second are trivial:

```
interface First { }

interface Second { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if you could, what would be the output of this code?

```
var dict = new BijectiveDictionary<int, int>();

dict.Add(2,3);
dict.Add(3,4);

Console.WriteLine(dict[3]); // Do I get 2 or 4?
```

Maybe you can restructure your code in another way which isn't ambiguous?

Comment: You couldn't do this, because this would break the bijective nature of the dictionary (unless I'm misunderstanding bijection, which is possible.) `dict.Add(3,4);` would err because 3 is already mapped to 2.

Comment: @Vilx-: Exactly, that is why I used another approach. With my example, you would get implicitly 4 and explicitly 2.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen: 3 is not mapped to 2. 3 is mapped to 4. You have to understand that `3 from set A` is different from `3 from set B`.
My examply specifically differentiates between the 2 sets (detectable by a reference pointer).

Comment: Again, perhaps I misunderstand bijection, but my belief is that for all values `f(X) = Y`, then `g(Y) = X`. Therefore, 3 *is* mapped to 4.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen Yes, you are right. But consider this: In my example if f(2)=3, then g(3)=2. And, if f(3)=4, then g(4)=3. No conflict with your definition as you can see. But since `dict[3]` does not specify whether you want `g(x)` or `f(x)`, you can't really pick the right value. If the types were different you could infer from them which one you want, but in my example I deliberately made the types equal.

Comment: @Daniel Rasmussen: Again, you have to understand that it is an operation on sets => `f(3) = 4` and `f(3) = 2`. It looks like it is wrong, it is not. You should really see it as: `f(X3) = Y4` and `f(Y3) = X2`, therefore it is a valid bijection.
For it to work you would **have to** specify the bijection mapping explicitly (which I do), because .NET does not "see" the difference between X3 and Y3 (3 from different sets). So **Vilx-'s** point is very much correct - it does not provide a solution, though.
Btw. my code works for any scenario and IMHO it is much more intuitive than the other ways.