# Implementing twice the same generic interface, with type argument constraints

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

Having

```
public interface IGeneric<T>{}

public class Student{}

public class Teacher{}
```

this is possible

```
public class ConcreateClass : IGeneric<Student>, IGeneric<Teacher>{}
```

this is not possible

```
public class GenericClass<T1, T2> : IGeneric<T1>, IGeneric<T2> {}
```

because `GenericClass<String, String> instance;` would cause ambiguity for the two interface implementation. But why this is not possible

```
public class GenericClassWithTypeConstraints<T1, T2> : IGeneric<T1>, IGeneric<T2>
    where T1 : Student
    where T2 : Teacher
{}
```

as T1 and T2 cannot be of the same class? (The compiler error is the same as in the case without type constrains)

**Edit**
"Soner Gönül" in  [Why does this result in CS0695](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695#) proposed a workarround, using two levels of class inheritance, like this:

```
public interface IGeneric<T> { String Name { get; } }

public class Student{}

public class Teacher{}

public class GenericClassBase<T1> : IGeneric<T1>
    where T1 : Student
{ String IGeneric<T1>.Name { get { return "Generic class of Student"; } } }

public class GenericClassDerived<T1, T2> : GenericClassBase<T1>, IGeneric<T2>
    where T1 : Student
    where T2 : Teacher
{ String IGeneric<T2>.Name { get { return "Generic class of Teacher"; } } }
```

Code like this then produce expected result

```
GenericClassDerived<Student, Teacher> X = new GenericClassDerived<Student, Teacher>();
Console.WriteLine(((IGeneric<Student>)X).Name); //outputs "Generic class of Student"
Console.WriteLine(((IGeneric<Teacher>)X).Name); //outputs "Generic class of Teacher"
```

Comment: See: [Why does the C# compiler complain that “types may unify” when they derive from different base classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664790/why-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-complain-that-types-may-unify-when-they-derive-f), which is very similar.

Comment: Found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695) by searching on CS0695. The answer includes spec references including: "Constraint declarations are not considered when determining all possible constructed types."

Comment: @Ani Thanks, now I understand that this is not possible by definition of C#. This is probably the case also for VB.

Comment: @Damien_The_UnbelieverThanks. In your link I have found a contribution of Soner Gönül, that is a sort of workarround, I will place it to my original answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use same interface two times with diferrent template parameters, in an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287010/how-to-use-same-interface-two-times-with-diferrent-template-parameters-in-an-in)

Answer (score 1):

> as T1 and T2 cannot be of the same class?

Yes, they can be the same class. Constraints cannot be [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) classes<sup>1</sup> so `Teacher` can be derived from `Student` or vise versa. It's not logical but compiler has no idea about it.

For example,

```
using System;

public class Student{}

public class Teacher : Student{}

public class GenericClassWithTypeConstraints<T1, T2>
    where T1 : Student
    where T2 : Teacher
{}

class Test {
    static void Main() {
        var obj = new GenericClassWithTypeConstraints<Teacher, Teacher>();
    }
}
```

will compile without any problem. [Demo](http://ideone.com/SvF1ND)

---

1. > [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a174071k.aspx):
   >
   > Constraints can also be class types, such as abstract base classes.
   >   However, constraints cannot be value types or sealed classes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My point was that `Student` and `Teacher` __doesn't__ inherits from each other. But as others answered, it doesn't matter, because type constraints are not considered.

Comment: Constraints cannot be sealed classes is logical. The sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.